# Can't create hibernate mapping files via JBoss Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, eclipse-luna, jboss-tools

I installed the J[Boss Tools 4.2.1](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/) for Eclipse Luna. I am trying to use the wizard to generate a hibernat emapping file (hbm.xml). I'm walking through the wizard, selecting my class to generate a map from, and see the preview of the contents of the file. I'm following the steps [here](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/#map_file_wizard), although the wizrad is pretty straighforward and simple.

However, the file doesn't get written out to the hard disk on Windows 7, there's no reference to it in my project, and there are no errors that I see.

The final page of the wizard says, under the set of Changes to be performed, "Create file /path/to/file/MyClass.hbm.xml with the preview. Clicking Finish exits the wizard with no file built.

Edit: I have an error in the Event Log as follows:
Resource 'ProjectName/package/path/to/domain/object/' does not exist.

The package definitely exists.. I selected the data object in the wizard.

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource 'ProjectName/package/path/to/domain/object/' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.nls.changes.CreateFileChange.perform(CreateFileChange.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingPreviewPage.performFinish(NewHibernateMappingPreviewPage.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.performFinish(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Do you have errors in Eclipse Error Log View? Would be also good to run eclipse from command processor and check if there are any system out messages.

Comment: @dgolovin yes, there are errors. See my edited response.

Comment: It there a stcktrace or just this message?

Comment: OK, I added the stack trace. So, my fields are called m_bob, with a setter and getter named getBob() and setBob(). I wonder if the field prefix is throwing it off? The previewed file, however, seems to understand it OK. Edit: Nope, that doesn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be known problem [JBIDE-18769 ResourceException when generating hbm.xml](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-18769)